# Firebase push notification delivery report

Tags: firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

we're using fcm api to send push notifications to our android/ios/web clients. Clients getting notifications as well but delivery report in firebase console is always zero for received messages. Any idea to show this stat correctly?

[image]

Comment: I have the same issue - would love to know if any update on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case that was because of overriding `handleIntent` function in `FirebaseMessagingService`. So with removing this function from service the problem fixed.